# Is it possible to change the automatically created "sample page" in WordPress multisite?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the need to change the default name and slug of the "Sample Page" to the name of the created site (in WordPress multisite) and make the Sample Page the front page of that site.

So it a user registers a new site called "Michaels Cats", the then created "Sample Page" should also be named "Michaels Cats" and be set as frontpage of multisite.com/michaelscats

I'd also like to automatically redirect the user to edit this page once she's logged in.

- Is it possible to write a function that would edit this SQL database and replace the name and slug of Sample Page?
- Is it possible to use WordPress translating and a function to change

  'post_title' => __( 'Sample Page' ),
- or should I just hack the core file?

Thank you!

Comment: 'Sample Page' is a translatable string. You could use a localisation file to change the text to something of your choosing

Comment: How should I proceed with this? The site is in english and the original string too, is it a problem?

Comment: Check out the [Translating WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress) article. You'll need to use something like Poedit.

Comment: Thanks. I've made translations before but it was more clear since I was translating from english to finnish. I really don't know how to go about translating from english to english. Any thoughts or resources I should read?

Comment: Using Poedit as the example, take a look at the steps in this article: http://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/tools/poedit/#uploading-your-translations

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into `wpmu_new_blog` and modify the page:

```
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'new_site_so_24355774', 10, 6 );

function new_site_so_24355774( $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta )
{
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    // Use $user_id to grab the user name : get_userdata( $user_id );
    // Use wp_update_post to modify the Sample page : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

<sub>*Related: [Populate content on install](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/75420/12615)*</sub>